# Soundmanager 2, whatever I try, I cant setup the SWF path

Tags: javascript, html, flash, soundmanager2

I am currently since weeks trying to set up soundmanager2 to find my swf folder which is in my root website folder. This will enable flash fallback. Im trying so hard to find the piece of code where I set up the path, went through it so many times.

I also, as shown in the documentation, added this code in the head of my html:

```
soundManager.setup({
  url: '/path/to/swfs/',
  flashVersion: 9,
  onready: function() {
    // console.log('SM2 ready!');
  },
  ontimeout: function() {
    // console.log('SM2 init failed!');
  },
  defaultOptions: {
    // set global default volume for all sound objects
    volume: 33
  }
});
```

The bottom code is the minified version of the soundmanager2.js code.

http://jsfiddle.net/VUwFF/1/

Soundmanagers core files only include this javascript file, 2 swf files, 2 css files and that is pretty much it. I dont know what im missing out.

Thank you in advance and please make the answer as easy as possible to understand :-) 
(im new to js)

Comment: Just in case: http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/

Comment: Your fiddle only contains the schillmania code...

Answer (score 0):

```
soundManager.setup({
   flashVersion: 9,
   preferFlash: false,
   useHighPerformance: true, // keep flash on screen, boost performance
   wmode: 'transparent', // transparent SWF, if possible
   url:  'http://www.hiding-my-file/Soundmanager2Files/soundmanager2_flash9.swf/'
 });
```

In one of Soundmanager's script, I found they put it at the end of the setup. It works for me.